# Deploying SSO for AWS EC2 Instance Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, single-sign-on, mean-stack, bitnami

I have a MEAN Stack application running on Amazon EC2 Instance. I want users to sign in to the application using a Single Sign On(SSO). Can you suggest some way in which I can authenticate the user for the application through SSO ?

Please note I do not want to provide the users access to the AWS Management Console. I am aware of authentication through SSO for AWS Management Console. I am looking for an application specific authentication through SSO for an Application deployed on Amazon EC2 Instance.

Amazon EC2 Instance Used: 
MEAN powered by Bitnami.

PS: I want to use SSO because that is a requirement for the project.

Comment: Single sign-on (SSO) is a session/user authentication process that permits a user to enter one name and password in order to access multiple applications. In your question there is only one application that the user will be accessing. Are you asking about allowing the user to login with a social network identity using OAuth?

Comment: I am planning to deploy two more applications for the same set of users and i want a single authentication for each of the applications. So i am trying to search a way in which i can do that. I am unable to find some link which provides authentication through SSO for EC2 Applications specifically. I have found many links which point me for authentication to AWS Management Console but that is what I don't want.

Comment: Part of the problem is that there is nothing special about EC2 applications, they are just applications running on standard Linux virtual machines. There is nothing about EC2 that is going to provide a login for your application. Since you are using a MEAN stack I would simply look into the Passport plugin or Auth0.